# How to pass a C++ function into a C one that takes function pointer with unspecified parameter?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

My C dependency library (edit: actually we're writing a Postgres extension so the dependency is Postgres 14.4) has a function

```c
bool expression_tree_walker(Node *node, bool (*walker) (), void *context)
```

in which the second parameter `bool (*walker) ()` takes *unspecified* number of parameters according to [https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration#:~:text=unspecified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration#:%7E:text=unspecified).

In my C++ code, I want to pass the function `static bool my_walker(Node *node, struct my_ctx *ctx)` into `expression_tree_walker`, but since C++ interprets `bool (*walker) ()` as a function that takes *no* parameter, passing it directly won't compile:

[image]

I know I can cast it into `bool (*) ()` but that won't pass the `-Wcast-function-type`  check that we are using. I also know I can use double-casting like `(bool (*) ()) (void (*) ()) my_walker` to suppress this warning but I think it's a bit hacky. Are there any recommended, better way to make this happen?

Comment: A quick dirty hack is to create a function wrapper that takes in a struct. The struct would contain all the parameters, then within this wrapper, run your function`my_walker`  with the various parameters. This function wrapper is what you pass into `expression_tree_walker`

Comment: `My C dependency library` Is it  POSTGRES? Why not say what library exctly? https://doxygen.postgresql.org/nodeFuncs_8h.html#aabcd790e4f040ba32edd5c7bb47e6623

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, it's Postgres hhh :-)

Comment: Then the callback is not `bool (*)()` it's defined https://doxygen.postgresql.org/nodeFuncs_8h.html#a7a1771d4e002f11e64690930e39759dd . Are you using an old version? And expression_tree_walker is a macro. `Are there any recommended, better way to make this happen?` You can write a small C wrapper functions that wraps the  `expression_tree_walker` function with proper function arguments types and use that wrapper from C++.

Comment: @KamilCuk You're right. Tom Lane authored a commit to change the signature in Sept 2022 https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3953550.1663376882%40sss.pgh.pa.us. as we're relying on Postgres 14.4 that's not useful. I'll try the wrapper though.

Comment: Is compiling the code as C23 an option? C23 compilers are in the experimental stage still, so buggy as can be. But in C23, C and C++ treats `bool (*)()` the same so that would solve the problem.

Comment: really declaration must be i think - `bool expression_tree_walker(Node *node, bool (*walker) (Node *, void*), void *context);`

Comment: @RbMm you're so right. they actually changed this in https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3953550.1663376882%40sss.pgh.pa.us to `typedef bool (*tree_walker_callback) (Node *node, void *context);`, but sadly because we're relying on Postgres 14.4 we cannot take advantage of this change.

Comment: @Lundin you mean C23 actually make `bool (*)()` no longer means unspecified number of parameters but actually `bool (*) (void)` as what C++ are already doing?

Comment: you can use `typedef bool (*tree_walker_callback) (Node *node, void *context);` in any version i sure, simply where is it defined as this or as `typedef bool (*tree_walker_callback) (...);` ? change one definition to latest

Comment: @RayEldath Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

There can’t be a very clean way of handling this, since the C declaration is simply **wrong** when interpreted as C++.  That said, the C type `bool()` is closest to the C/C++ type `bool(...)` and should be ABI compatible with it (as they both apply the default argument promotions).

The first step is thus to define your function to be **variadic** (even if all it does is invoke `va_arg` a couple of times and then call the real implementation).  Afterwards you can, with similar degrees of violence against the language, either add the ellipsis to the declaration of the callback parameter or cast the pointer to your function.  Any resulting warning is yours to keep.